# Create and populate the upper triangular matrix with a vector in R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I need to create a square matrix based on a vector of varying length where the indices of the vector populate the upper triangular only without recycling of the vector elements.

I tried the following R code:

```
# example vector (could be longer or shorter!)
v <- letters[1:8]
# calculate dimensions of square matrix
n <- ceiling((-1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * length(v))) / 2)
# create empty matrix
m <- matrix(NA, nrow=n, ncol=n)
# populate the matrix
m[lower.tri(m, diag=TRUE)] <- 1:length(v)
m <- t(m)
```

And the resulting matrix looks like that:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]   NA    5    6    7
[3,]   NA   NA    8    1
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    2
```

How can I populate the matrix in a way that only that part of the upper triangular is filled which does not require recycling of vector index elements?

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]   NA   NA    5    6
[3,]   NA   NA   NA    7
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    8
```

- no recycling of vector elements
- use the full dimensions (columns/rows) of the square matrix (maximize lower left "patch of NAs")

Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: just to confirm your output please: you want to fill the upper triangle matrix and the first and last diagonal entries?

Comment: I don't think this problem is fully specified. If you have a 4 x 4 matrix, how would you populate it with 3 elements? What if the vector had 16 elements? What if it had 11?

Comment: The dimensions of the matrix are adjusted depending on the vector length (see code). If (by chance) the vector length fits to the square matrix dimensions, (e.g. 6, 10 or 15 elements vector) then the above code produces a correct matrix. The problem are the in-betweens (e.g. 7,8,9 etc elements vectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
f <- function(v) {
  n <- length(v)
  # number of rows of the square matrix
  m <- ceiling(sqrt(0.25 + 2*n) - 0.5)
  x <- array(NA, rep(m, 2))
  s <- pmin(m + 1L - row(x), col(x)) + pmax(m + 1L - row(x), col(x))/n + (m + 1L)*upper.tri(x)
  x[sort(order(s)[1:n])] <- v
  t(x)
}
```

Testing vectors up to length 14:

```
lapply(1:14, \(i) f(1:i))
#> [[1]]
#>      [,1]
#> [1,]    1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    2
#> [2,]   NA   NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    2
#> [2,]   NA    3
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    3
#> [2,]   NA   NA    4
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    3
#> [2,]   NA   NA    4
#> [3,]   NA   NA    5
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    2    3
#> [2,]   NA    4    5
#> [3,]   NA   NA    6
#> 
#> [[7]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4
#> [2,]   NA   NA   NA    5
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA    6
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA    7
#> 
#> [[8]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4
#> [2,]   NA   NA    5    6
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA    7
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA    8
#> 
#> [[9]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4
#> [2,]   NA    5    6    7
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA    8
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA    9
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4
#> [2,]   NA    5    6    7
#> [3,]   NA   NA    8    9
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   10
#> 
#> [[11]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [2,]   NA   NA    6    7    8
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    9
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   10
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   11
#> 
#> [[12]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [2,]   NA   NA    6    7    8
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA    9   10
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   11
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   12
#> 
#> [[13]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [2,]   NA    6    7    8    9
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA   10   11
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   12
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   13
#> 
#> [[14]]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#> [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
#> [2,]   NA    6    7    8    9
#> [3,]   NA   NA   NA   10   11
#> [4,]   NA   NA   NA   12   13
#> [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   14
```

Comment: Thanks jblood94! Love this approach which works well and without additional libs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try

```
t(
    replace(
        m,
        t(!is.na(cbind(rbind(replace(
            matrix(1, n - 1, n - 1),
            seq(n^2 - length(v)), NA
        ), 1), 1)[n:1, ])),
        seq_along(v)
    )
)
```

which gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]   NA   NA    5    6
[3,]   NA   NA   NA    7
[4,]   NA   NA   NA    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose a non-increasing integer n-vector x such that 1 <= x <= n:1 and sum(x) equals length(v).  x[i] represents the number of non-NA elements in row i of the result matrix.

We do that by using CVXR to form the convex optimization problem such that any feasible value provides that.  When defining the problem below xval is the final value of x produced.  The solution it found was c(4, 2, 1, 1) but as the question is not well defined c(3, 2, 2, 1) would be another valid solution and we could add additional constraints if it were desired to constrain the solution further.

Given xval form a logical matrix m which is like the transpose of the result and show which entries are non-NA using TRUE.  Since R stores matrices column by column it is easier to fill in the transpose.  Finally fill it and then take the transpose to get the result M.

```
v <- letters[1:8]
n <- ceiling((-1 + sqrt(1 + 8 * length(v))) / 2)

library(CVXR)
x <- Variable(n, integer = TRUE)
objective <- Minimize(0)
constraints <- list(sum(x) == length(v), diff(x) <= 0, x >= 1, x <= n:1)
problem <- Problem(objective, constraints)
soln <- solve(problem)
xval <- as.integer(soln$getValue(x) + 0.01)
xval
## [1] 4 2 1 1

m <- matrix(NA, n, n)
m[sapply(c(xval), function(i) rep(c(F, T), c(n-i, i)))] <- seq_along(v)
M <- t(m)

M
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4
## [2,]   NA   NA    5    6
## [3,]   NA   NA   NA    7
## [4,]   NA   NA   NA    8
```